# PHP form validation code used to work fine, stopped working and I don't know why

Tags: php, validation

I have some pretty basic php validation code on my site and it has worked for quite some time. I'm not a php expert by any means (obvious below i'm sure) :), but this code has worked fine for my needs up until now... I recently realized this code has stopped working and I am not sure why. Any help would be appreciated. I thought maybe something changed on the server so I chatted with my host company and they assured me nothing has changed and that it has to be a code error.

Here is the basic portions of the code:

```
<?php // Handle the form submission

    // VALIDATE Forms Required Fileds       
    //Check for name.       
    if (strlen($_POST['name']) > 0 ){
        $name = $name;
    } else {
        $name = NULL;
    }   

    //Check email was entered
    if (strlen($_POST['email'])=='') {
        $email = NULL;
    } elseif(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $_POST['email'])) {
        $email = "invalid";
    } else {
        $email = $email;
    }
    // END VALIDATION

    // If all is ok then handle form
    if ((isset($_POST['Submit']) || isset($_POST['Submit_x'])) && ($name && $email && $email != "invalid"))
    {       
        // Capture information and format for email
        $subject="Side Nav Form"; // Subject of Email

        $body = "Contact Us:\n\n";      
        $body .="Name..............: " ."$name\n";
        $body .="Email.............: " ."$email\n";
        $body .="Phone.............: " ."$phone\n\n";
        $body .="Reason for inquiry: " ."$inquiryReason1, $inquiryReason2, $inquiryReason3\n";
        $body .="Current Website...: " ."$current_site\n\n";
        $body .="Comments/Questions: " ."$addtlComments\n";

        //Email form results
        mail("xxx@xxx.com", $subject, $body, "From:" .$email);

        // Display thank you Message if form submitted successfully.
        echo '<h3>Thank you!</h3><p>We received your information and will get back to you as soon as possible.</p>';

    } else {    

        // If Validating form: Show validation errors.
        if ((isset($_POST['Submit']) || isset($_POST['Submit_x'])) && (!$name || !$email || $email == "invalid")) { 
        echo '<p class="error">';
             if (!$name) {
                    echo "*Please enter your name.<br />";
                    }
             if (!$email) {
                    echo "*Please enter your email address.<br />";
                    } 
             if ($email == "invalid") {
                    echo "*Please enter a valid email address. (xxx@xxx.xxx)";
                    } 
        echo '</p>';
        }
    // Display the form if user has not submitted successfully or at all.
?>
<fieldset><label for="name">*Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['name'])) echo $_POST['name']; ?>" /></fieldset>
<fieldset><label for="email">*Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>" /></fieldset>

... rest of form fields...

<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>
<?php       
    } // End of Form Handler
?>
```

Comment: `stopped working and I don't know why` and neither do we. What error messages are you getting?

Comment: What error is presented to you?

Comment: Shot in the dark: your server's php version has been changed to a 5.3.* and E_STRICT errors are flying about all over the place?

Comment: Comments on your email regex: no `.asia` email addresses will work, no emails containing `+` delivery specifiers, no `#` signs, no pipes, no IP-address domain names... Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part and please consider not using home-brewed regexes for "validating" email addresses.

Comment: I am not getting any error messages. It just doesn't submit. The only error message i see is that it will say the email or name isn't filled out even though it is.

Comment: @SOliver: I was thinking the same thing about the server php's version changing but it hasn't and the hosting tech support said nothing has changed on the servers.

Comment: I figured out what the issue was, but hopefully the solution is ok??  I had a php.ini file that set registered globals to 0, I changed it to 1 and then my forms worked again. Is it ok that I did this?

Answer (score 1):

`eregi()` is deprecated. Use `preg_match()` instead. You could also use `filter_var(email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` to validate emails as well.